# Delete emojis or replace for text using regex in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have this toy dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'text':['Oh no Monday','Oh no Monday','Gotcha !',
                           'Coffee, please','Coffee, please','Mails '],
                   'dates':['2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000','2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000',
                           '2019-05-25T19:40:43+0000','2019-03-30T14:41:20+0000',
                           '2019-03-30T14:41:20+0000','2019-04-10T19:50:49+0000'],
                   'group':['meme','humour','meme','gif','gif','meme'],
                   'theme':['light','light','funny','dark','sad','funny']})

id  text    dates   group   theme
0   1   Oh no Monday    2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000    meme    light
1   2   Oh no Monday    2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000    humour  light
2   3   Gotcha !    2019-05-25T19:40:43+0000    meme    funny
3   4   Coffee, please  2019-03-30T14:41:20+0000    gif dark
4   5   Coffee, please  2019-03-30T14:41:20+0000    gif sad
5   6   Mails     2019-04-10T19:50:49+0000    meme    funny
```

I want to either delete the emojis or replace the emoji for text. I tried this:

```
df['clean_text'] = df['text'].str.extract(r'(^[a-zA-Z]+)')
```

But it deletes my longer texts, for example I want `Oh no Monday` but I get only `Oh`!:

```
id  text                dates                       group   theme   clean_text
0   1   Oh no Monday    2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000    meme    light   Oh
1   2   Oh no Monday    2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000    humour  light   Oh
2   3   Gotcha !        2019-05-25T19:40:43+0000    meme    funny   Gotcha
3   4   Coffee, please  2019-03-30T14:41:20+0000    gif dark    Coffee
4   5   Coffee, please  2019-03-30T14:41:20+0000    gif sad Coffee
5   6   Mails         2019-04-10T19:50:49+0000    meme    funny   Mails
```

Please, any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `df['clean_text'] = df['text'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s!\"£$%\^&\*()_+=\-\-\[\]}{#'';:@~/\.,<>\?\|]', '')`

Comment: Thank you @MDR, right to the point answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete emojis using regex:

```
pat = r'[\U0001F600-\U0001F64F]|[\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF]|[\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF]|[\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF]'
```

```
>>> df['text'].str.replace(pat, '', regex=True)
0      Oh no Monday
1      Oh no Monday
2          Gotcha !
3    Coffee, please
4    Coffee, please
5            Mails
Name: text, dtype: object
```

A complete list:

```
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block
EMOJI_PATTERN = re.compile(
    "["
    "\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
    "\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
    "\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
    "\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
    "\U0001F700-\U0001F77F"  # alchemical symbols
    "\U0001F780-\U0001F7FF"  # Geometric Shapes Extended
    "\U0001F800-\U0001F8FF"  # Supplemental Arrows-C
    "\U0001F900-\U0001F9FF"  # Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs
    "\U0001FA00-\U0001FA6F"  # Chess Symbols
    "\U0001FA70-\U0001FAFF"  # Symbols and Pictographs Extended-A
    "\U00002702-\U000027B0"  # Dingbats
    "\U000024C2-\U0001F251" 
    "]+"
)

df['text'].str.replace(EMOJI_PATTERN, '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Thank you @Corralien, it works fine! Interesting to learn about such emoji codes!.